# Action que devolve PartialView não está sendo chamada

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

Preciso apresentar uma lista de resultados conforme o preenchimento do formulário abaixo, mas a pesquisa não está apresentando o resultado.
A *action* na *controller* não está sendo acionada.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProfissionalID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("ProfissionalID", Model.Profissionais, "", new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "chosen-select" }, { "data-placeholder", "Selecione" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProfissionalID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" value="Pesquisar" class="btn btn-default" onclick="return efetuarPesquisa()" />
    </div>
</div>
}

<div id="resultado">

</div>

function efetuarPesquisa() {
if (!$('#ProfissionalID').val()) {
    $.MessageBox("Selecione o profissional");
    $('#ProfissionalID').focus();
    return false;
}

$("#resultado").load('/Lancamento/BuscarLancamentosProfissional/' + $("#ProfissionalID").val());
return true;
}
```

Action que fará o preenchimento da lista:

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult BuscarLancamentosProfissional(int profissionalId)
{
    var model = _edicaoMapper.Mapear(_lancamentoService.BuscarLancamentosProfissional(profissionalId));
    return PartialView("Edit", model);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Você colocou o `verb` no método `BuscarLancamentosProfissional` `POST`, e chamou por um evento [Javascript com JQuery.load (load)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3870130/6797930), que chama o verb `get`, então, quando envia a requisição para o servidor dá erro, porque, não acha o método com o `verb` ***correto***

Para solucionar, troque `[HttpPost]` por `[HttpGet]` no ***método*** `BuscarLancamentosProfissional`:

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult BuscarLancamentosProfissional(int profissionalId)
{
    var model = _edicaoMapper.Mapear(_lancamentoService
                                         .BuscarLancamentosProfissional(profissionalId));
    return PartialView("Edit", model);
}
```

***ou***

troque:

```
$("#resultado")
         .load('/Lancamento/BuscarLancamentosProfissional/' + $("#ProfissionalID").val());
```

por [JQuery $.post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/):

```
$.post( "/Lancamento/BuscarLancamentosProfissional/" + $("#ProfissionalID").val(), 
 function( data ) {
  $("#resultado").html( data );
});
```

nesse caso não precisando mexer no método `BuscarLancamentosProfissional`, porque, o `verb` nesse caso foi enviado correto.

Answer (score 1):

Do jeito que você está usando o método .load() vai ser feito via GET. Para ser feito via POST você deve passar o parâmetro como objeto. Fica assim:

```
$("#resultado").load('/Lancamento/BuscarLancamentosProfissional/', { profissionalId: $("#ProfissionalID").val() }, function (){
    return true; 
});
```